# My MacBook Pro gets a kernel panic on shutdown or reboot

Tags: macos, virtual-memory, kernel-panic

My Macbook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012) kernel panic every time when shutdown or reboot. I'm currently using OS X 10.11 El Capitan. How can I solve this issue?

Here is the panic report

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff80080a97df): "(default pager): [KERNEL]: default memory manager"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.60.10/osfmk/default_pager/default_pager.c:421
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81f3bbbdb0 : 0xffffff80080dab52 
0xffffff81f3bbbe30 : 0xffffff80080a97df 
0xffffff81f3bbbe60 : 0xffffff80080a962b 
0xffffff81f3bbbe80 : 0xffffff800813ccd1 
0xffffff81f3bbbef0 : 0xffffff8008623c54 
0xffffff81f3bbbf10 : 0xffffff80081b8eca 
0xffffff81f3bbbfb0 : 0xffffff80081ecd86 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: logind
Boot args: vm_compressor=1

Mac OS version:
15G31

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 23 18:25:34 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: B5AA8E3E-65B6-3D0E-867B-8DCCF81E536C
Kernel slide:     0x0000000007e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8008000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8007f00000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-***C7CD******81F)
```

Comment: Kernel panic can also be a variety of sources - you need to read error logs and see where it is coming from

Answer (score 0):

There are many sources will cause a kernel panic. For this case, the root cause is disabled compressed memory.

First, please make sure compressed memory is disabled with Terminal

```
sysctl -a vm.compressor_mode
```

The output is like:

```
vm.compressor_mode: 1 --> Disabled
vm.compressor_mode: 4 --> Enabled (Default)
```

If compressed memory is disabled, you can reset NVRAM by booting with holding [Option+Cmd+P+R](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063).

Alternatively, you can reset NVRAM boot-args with Terminal. But use this way cautiously.

```
sudo nvram boot-args=""
```

After reset NVRAM, compressed memory will be enabled by default.

Edit: Thanks to @jrodatus for providing another way to reset NVRAM.

Comment: In some some cases, the `sudo nvram ...` command may get undone/reversed on reboot after a crash, which can cause the problem to persist (as it was in my case). Booting with [Cmd+Option+P+R](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) is another way to reset the `boot-args`